# Elementary calculus?

Tags: calculus

Can anybody see why $${d\over dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty -f_{xx}+f^2\,\,\, dx=0$$ where $f=f(x,t)$, follows from $$f_t+f_{xxx}+6ff_x=0$$?

I tried differentiating under the integral sign, but things got ugly.

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: I don't see how this could follow independently of the trajectory $x(t)$. Are you sure you intended that to be a total derivative with respect to time and not a partial derivative?

Comment: @joriki unfortunately so...

Comment: @martini It is from a handout I got, it is talking about 1st integrals of the [Korteweg–de_Vries_equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg–de_Vries_equation)

Answer (score 2):

This is false. A counterexample is afforded by $f(x,0)=\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}$. At $t=0$, we have $f_x(x,0)=-x\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}$, $f_{xx}(x,0)=(x^2-1)\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}$, and $f_{xxx}(x,0)=(3x-x^3)\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}$. Thus $f_t(x,0)=(x^3-3x)\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}+6(1-x^2)\mathrm e^{-x^2}$. Then at $t=0$

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(-f_{xx}+f^2\right)\mathrm dx
&=
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2\mathrm dx
\\
&=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(f^2\right)\mathrm dx
\\
&=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty ff_t\,\mathrm dx
\\
&=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left((x^3-3x)\mathrm e^{-x^2}+6(1-x^2)\mathrm e^{-3x^2/2}\right)\mathrm dx
\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{32\pi}3}
\end{align}
$$

([computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%28x%5E3-3x%29exp%28-x%5E2%29%20%2b%206%281-x%5E2%29exp%28-3x%5E2/2%29%20for%20x=-infinity..infinity)).